# Microsoft Office 365 cloud not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, ubuntu-22.04, microsoft-teams

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and I noticed that it has many problems, especially with Microsoft products. I use Microsoft Teams as a work tool so I always need it, and I can't seem to be able to use it on the web. It displays the following message:

> In order to open the web app, change your browser settings to allow third-party cookies or allow certain trusted domains.

I tried every third party Teams For Linux apps and none of them worked. I did the following steps to solve the problem but in vain:

1. Use Firefox;
2. Add these links to exceptions:

   - `https://microsoft.com`
   - `https://microsoftonline.com`
   - `https://teams.skype.com`
   - `https://teams.microsoft.com`
   - `https://sfbassets.com`
   - `https://skypeforbusiness.com`
3. Disable Enhanced Tracking Protection;
4. Use Google Chrome;
5. Add these links to exceptions:

   - `*.microsoft.com`
   - `*.microsoftonline.com`
   - `*.teams.skype.com`
   - `*.teams.microsoft.com`
   - `*.sfbassets.com`
   - `*.skypeforbusiness.com`
6. Allow third-party cookies

And nothing!

Also, I cannot access my Office365 emails in Thunderbird, Mailspring, and any other Email client. It says: SMTP Error.

I did telnet `smtp.office365.com 587` and it gives me the correct response.

So many issues, I tried everything! What to do?